# How to specify a maximum number of characters allowed in an input element - Is setting a maxlength attribute enough?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to set the maximum number of characters allowed in an input element. Is using the `maxlength` attribute enough or do I need some further PHP or JavaScript validation?

This is what I have so far:

`<input type="text" name="field-1" maxlength="20" />`

Comment: It is sufficient (though annoying) in terms of the client UI. However, it is certainly insufficient in terms of server validation, that must always be a separate exercise and assume no client validation has occurred at all.

Comment: Are you saying the maxlength attribute can be bypassed?

Comment: This should be enough for the client - if you trust the client. As you should never trust the client, you should make sure on the server as well, that you have only xx characters received.

Comment: Never trust user's input. Always validate. Always validate on the server side. Too long strings can cause problems, especially if you try to store a too long string in - lets say - the PostgreSQL database (it will not quietly trim it like MySQL would do).

Comment: @henriwright sure, you can post / get with any data to your servlet. A common break into backend systems (when they were written in c or other pointer languages), was sending a URL to the server that caused a buffer overflow.

Comment: @henrywright—yes, because you can't trust the client to implement any part of a standard, nor can you trust that the user isn't bypassing the UI (e.g. using anyone of of a number of methods to circumvent the *maxlength* attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client-side: yes, as [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-maxlength) says:

> When the type attribute has the value "text" or "password", this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters the user may enter.

Although, as @RobG mentioned, you **have to** validate data on server-side (e.g. PHP).

HTML input `maxlength` **can be easily bypassed** e.g with JavaScript.
Consider the following fiddle, that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2YUca/

Comment: Thanks for building on @RobG's comment. It is all quite clear now. I must validate both on the client and on the server.

Comment: You could also just remove the attribute all together with javascript.
ie: `$('input').removeAttr("maxlength");` Then you can bypass without having to inject text into it via javascript.

Comment: You're right, of course. There are thousands of ways, really - off the top of my head: manipulaing 'name' attribute to make server interpret other input's `value` as ours.

Answer (score 0):

In internet explorer 9 > maxlenght does not work for `<textarea>` fields.  To get this to work you'll need to add some JS  This example uses jQuery, but you could do it just as easily with standard JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('textarea').on('keyup', function () {
    // Store the maxlength and value of the field.
    if (!maxlength) {
        var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
    }
    var val = $(this).val();
    var vallength = val.length;

    // alert
    if (vallength >= maxlength) {


        alert('Please limit your response to ' + maxlength + ' characters');
        $(this).blur();
    }


    // Trim the field if it has content over the maxlength.
    if (vallength > maxlength) {
        $(this).val(val.slice(0, maxlength));
    }
});

//remove maxlength on blur so that we can reset it later.
$('textarea').on('blur', function () {
    delete maxlength;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Using php you can use the strlen() functio